# Can I apply MacBuntu themes and icons on Xubuntu 16.04?

Tags: xubuntu, 16.04, themes, icons, macbuntu

[MacBuntu 16.04](http://www.noobslab.com/2016/04/macbuntu-1604-transformation-pack-for.html) is supposed to be compatible with XFCE. Fonts and cursors work, but when I apply the themes and icons on Xubuntu 16.04, nothing happens.

How can I apply these icons and themes (or something similar) on Xubuntu 16.04?

Comment: How do you apply them?

Comment: @BharadwajRaju In Unity you do it through the Unity Tweak Tool. In Gnome you do it through the Gnome Tweak Tool.  But that doesn't work in  XFCE for the themes and icons.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju The Macbuntu themes and icons are quite complex, can I really reproduce them manually?

Comment: Xfce has such settings by default, no need for third-party customization tools. Use *Settings Manager* → *Appearance* for GTK theme and icons, and *Settings Manager* → *Window Manager* for themeing the window borders.

Comment: Theme development is a *really* difficult thing, and is not helped by the fact that the GNOME developers radically change the themeing API every release.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju Right. But it would be easier if I could just apply the themes provided by Nooblabs, which they claim is possible.

Comment: Of course. But did you try to use the Noobslabs-provided themes with the comment in which I said that you have to use Xfce's *Settings Manager*?

Comment: @BharadwajRaju Yes, I tried it just now, and it worked :D Thanks! You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xfce uses GTK+ (just like GNOME, Unity and Pantheon). However, it does not require any external 'Tweak Tools' (unlike GNOME, Unity and Pantheon) because it is very customizable by default — all settings are included and change-able by default.

To change the GTK+ theme and the icons, use *Settings Manager* → *Appearance*.

To change window borders, use *Settings Manager* → *Window Manager*.